# Cannot see the target added to service monitor for Prometheus Operator

Tags: service, terraform, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, monitor

I am trying to set up to add the target to my service monitor for Prometheus Operator (inside my terraform that is using helm chart to deploy prometheus, prometheus operator and service monitor and a bunch of stuff).
After I successfully deployed service monitor, I cannot see the new target `app.kubernetes.io/instance: jobs-manager` in prometheus. I am not sure what I did wrong in my configuration. I am also checking this [document](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting-servicemonitor-changes) to see what is missing but cannot figure it out yet.
Here are some configuration files concerned:

1. `/helm/charts/prometheus-abcd/templates/service_monitor.tpl`

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: jobs-manager-servicemonitor
  # Change this to the namespace the Prometheus instance is running in
  namespace: prometheus
  labels:
    app: jobs-manager
    release: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: jobs-manager # Targets jobs-manager service
  endpoints:
  - port: http
    interval: 15s
```

2. `/helm/charts/prometheus-abcd/Chart.yaml`

```
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

apiVersion: v1
appVersion: "1.0.0"
description: Prometheus Service monitor, customized for abcd
name: prometheus-abcd
version: 1.0.0
```

3. `/terraform/kubernetes/helm_values/prometheus.yaml`

```
prometheus:
  podMetadata:
    annotations:
      container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/prometheus-operator: runtime/default
      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default

nodeAffinityPreset:
  ## Node affinity type
  ## Allowed values: soft, hard
  ##
  type: "hard"
  ## Node label key to match
  ## E.g.
  ## key: "kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name"
  ##
  key: "cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool"
  ## Node label values to match
  ## E.g.
  ## values:
  ##   - e2e-az1
  ##   - e2e-az2
  ##
  values: [
    "abcd-primary-pool"
  ]

prometheus:
  configMaps:
    - prometheus-config

## ServiceMonitors to be selected for target discovery.
## If {}, select all ServiceMonitors
##
serviceMonitorSelector: {
  jobs-manager-servicemonitor
}
# matchLabels:
#   foo: bar

## Namespaces to be selected for ServiceMonitor discovery.
## See https://github.com/prometheusoperator/prometheusoperator/blob/master/
## Documentation/api.md#namespaceselector for usage
##
serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {
  matchNames: prometheus
}
```

When running this command:
`kubectl get -n prometheus prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus`
I can see that the service monitor was successfully deployed:

[image: serviceMonitordeployed]

But when I run this command:
`kubectl describe -n prometheus prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus`
I see that many parameters still have missing values such as `serviceMonitorSelector`

```
Name:         prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
Namespace:    prometheus
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=prometheus
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=prometheus
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=kube-prometheus
              helm.sh/chart=kube-prometheus-3.4.0
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: prometheus
API Version:  monitoring.coreos.com/v1
Kind:         Prometheus
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-05-26T15:19:42Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  monitoring.coreos.com/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name:
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name:
          f:helm.sh/chart:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:affinity:
          .:
          f:podAntiAffinity:
            .:
            f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        f:alerting:
          .:
          f:alertmanagers:
        f:configMaps:
        f:enableAdminAPI:
        f:externalUrl:
        f:image:
        f:listenLocal:
        f:logFormat:
        f:logLevel:
        f:paused:
        f:podMetadata:
          .:
          f:labels:
            .:
            f:app.kubernetes.io/component:
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance:
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name:
        f:podMonitorNamespaceSelector:
        f:podMonitorSelector:
        f:probeNamespaceSelector:
        f:probeSelector:
        f:replicas:
        f:retention:
        f:routePrefix:
        f:ruleNamespaceSelector:
        f:ruleSelector:
        f:securityContext:
          .:
          f:fsGroup:
          f:runAsUser:
        f:serviceAccountName:
        f:serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
        f:serviceMonitorSelector:
    Manager:         Go-http-client
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-05-26T15:19:42Z
  Resource Version:  11485229
  Self Link:         /apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/prometheus/prometheuses/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  UID:               xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Spec:
  Affinity:
    Pod Anti Affinity:
      Preferred During Scheduling Ignored During Execution:
        Pod Affinity Term:
          Label Selector:
            Match Labels:
              app.kubernetes.io/component:  prometheus
              app.kubernetes.io/instance:   prometheus
              app.kubernetes.io/name:       kube-prometheus
          Namespaces:
            prometheus
          Topology Key:  kubernetes.io/hostname
        Weight:          1
  Alerting:
    Alertmanagers:
      Name:         prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager
      Namespace:    prometheus
      Path Prefix:  /
      Port:         http
  Config Maps:
    prometheus-config
  Enable Admin API:  false
  External URL:      http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prometheus:9090/
  Image:             docker.io/bitnami/prometheus:2.24.0-debian-10-r1
  Listen Local:      false
  Log Format:        logfmt
  Log Level:         info
  Paused:            false
  Pod Metadata:
    Labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component:  prometheus
      app.kubernetes.io/instance:   prometheus
      app.kubernetes.io/name:       kube-prometheus
  Pod Monitor Namespace Selector:
  Pod Monitor Selector:
  Probe Namespace Selector:
  Probe Selector:
  Replicas:      1
  Retention:     10d
  Route Prefix:  /
  Rule Namespace Selector:
  Rule Selector:
  Security Context:
    Fs Group:            1001
    Run As User:         1001
  Service Account Name:  prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  Service Monitor Namespace Selector:
  Service Monitor Selector:
Events:  <none>
```

This is why I check this [document](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus/values.yaml) to get the template for `serviceMonitorSelector` and also `serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector` and added them to the `prometheus.yaml` file above but not sure if it is correctly added.

Anyone with experience setting up service monitor with helm and terraform, could you please help me check what I did wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way you have passed value in **prometheus.yaml** is wrong

```
serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {
  matchNames: prometheus
}                                  #this is wrong way
```

you should have to set the values like :

```
serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
       matchLabels:
         prometheus: somelabel
```

also same for

```
serviceMonitorSelector: {
  jobs-manager-servicemonitor
}
```

it's not set proper way.

for reference please check : https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/83aa113f52e5f45fd04b4dd909172a6da1826592/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2034

checkout this nice example : https://rtfm.co.ua/en/kubernetes-a-clusters-monitoring-with-the-prometheus-operator/

Prometheus operator with Terraform & helm : https://github.com/OpenQAI/terraform-helm-release-prometheus-operator

Comment: thank you very much, I will check the docs and change the config, I did check the first doc but it's missing some example so I didn't know what is the correct way

Comment: Thank you again @Harsh Manvar I followed another nice doc you sent and I progressed a bit more, now I can see the target but its down with the IP address that doesn't seem to correspond to the servicemonitor target that I added, so I am checking more in the doc. I will update the post with the solution once I find out.

Comment: Good to hear...! i would also suggest here to change the label and test the things out. if possible remove the label so by default Prometheus will monitor everything and you can find the issue.

Comment: finally I got it to work without having to add more config at all to prometheus.yaml, I only needed to modified config in `/helm/charts/prometheus-abcd/templates/service_monitor.tpl`, for the last part, I change the namespace to the correct namespace that my jobs-manager target is running on (its running in the different namespace as prometheus)